# pm2 --watch is logging every 3 seconds irrespective of config file

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, digital-ocean, pm2

We have the below config file for pm2:

```
module.exports = {
  apps: [
    {
      script: 'index.js',
      // ------------------------------------ watch options - begin
      watch: ['/testing'],
      watch_delay: 10000,
      ignore_watch: ['node_modules', 'logs'],
      watch_options: {
        followSymlinks: false,
      },
      // ------------------------------------ watch options - end
      error_file: 'logs/err.log',
      out_file: 'logs/out.log',
      log_file: 'logs/combined.log',
      time: true,
    },
  ],

  deploy: {
    production: {
      user: 'SSH_USERNAME',
      host: 'SSH_HOSTMACHINE',
      ref: 'origin/master',
      repo: 'GIT_REPOSITORY',
      path: 'DESTINATION_PATH',
      'pre-deploy-local': '',
      'post-deploy':
        'npm install && pm2 reload ecosystem.config.js --env production',
      'pre-setup': '',
    },
  },
};
```

With this in place, and a single `index.js` file:

```
console.log(`testing`);
```

We get 'testing printed to the log file every 3 seconds;

```
2021-05-31T12:02:39: testing
2021-05-31T12:02:42: testing
2021-05-31T12:02:45: testing
2021-05-31T12:02:48: testing
2021-05-31T12:02:51: testing
2021-05-31T12:02:55: testing
```

There are no changes to the files, and this isn't the `logs` directory or files being monitored as they're excluded with  `ignore_watch: ['node_modules', 'logs'],`.

Why isn't `--watch` only monitoring for file changes, and instead logging every 3 seconds?

Answer (score 1):

PM2 is detecting that your app is exiting and restarting your app.

You can [choose what PM2 should do when it detects when your app exists](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/restart-strategies/), such as `--no-autorestart`.

---

Example log output:

```
$ pm2 --watch --no-autorestart --ignore-watch=node_modules start index.js
$ pm2 logs -f

PM2        | App name:index id:0 online
0|index    | testing
PM2        | App [index] with id [0] and pid [48907], exited with code [0] via signal [SIGINT]

# Modify index.js to log `testing 2`.

PM2        | Change detected on path index.js for app index - restarting
PM2        | App name:index id:0 online
0|index    | testing 2
PM2        | App [index] with id [0] and pid [48910], exited with code [0] via signal [SIGINT]
```

Comment: `PM2 is detecting that your app is exiting and restarting your app.` <--- Useful feedback and makes sense thank you. 

However, with `exp_backoff_restart_delay: 1000` in place, file changes aren't monitored until the next back off period.

We would expect a file change to trigger an immediate log?

Comment: But that's exactly what it's there for: delaying restarts so you don't end up restarting a whole lot in a short span. So just leave it out. If you run `--watch --no-restart start index.js` it'll run once, exit & re-run when `index.js` changes.